# element return NaN as width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change an element's width when the window is resized. I am trying to get the element's width, but it returns `NaN`. This is my code for get width and to log it:

```
var widthItemMedia = parseInt($(".my-class .list-block .item-media i").css('width'));
console.log("Previous: " + lastWindowWidth + " Current: " + windowWidth + " Width " + widthItemMedia);
```

Comment: NaN can only result when the result is undefined, Boolean or null. Check if the selector's valid

Comment: Could you share your `css` and `html` code too? It would be always a good idea to create a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: @K3v1n that is incorrect. If the width value is "auto", the result (from the call to `parseInt()`) will be `NaN`.

Comment: Also, with `parseInt` both `5%` and `5px` will be parsed as just `5`. If that matters.

Comment: @Pointy sorry thanks for clarifying that :D

Comment: Not sure if this is know by the poster, but `NaN` stands for `Not A Number`. This by itself should point you to your issue.

Comment: `console.log($(".my-class .list-block .item-media i").css('width'))` returns what?

Comment: @epascarello return NaN

Comment: How would that return NAN?

Answer (score 6):

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/):

> The difference between `.css(width)` and `.width()` is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The `.width()` method is recommended when an element's width needs to be used in a mathematical calculation.

Use `.width()` when you want a number to work with:

```
var widthItemMedia = $(".my-class .list-block .item-media i").width();
```

You don't need the `parseInt()` either. The `parseInt()` function tolerates non-numeric stuff at the *end* of the input string, so "20px" is fine. However, something like "auto" is *not* fine. The `.width()` method gets you the actual layout width. See also the `.innerWidth()` and `.outerWidth()` methods, which can sometimes get you the answer you need depending on the situation.

Comment: Console now returns this `Previous: 678 Current: 1173 ElemWidth undefined`

Comment: @ВасяПупкин there's not enough code in the question to see what the problem is; the `console.log()` you posted does not include "ElemWidth" at all.